# choropleth() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bins' ​ on folium 0.5.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, choropleth

I am joining on an online course on Data science (to enriching my own skill set). This is the last project to be handed in for the course

The current request is to make a choropleth map.

This is my code

```
!conda install -c conda-forge folium=0.5.0 --yes 
import folium

!wget --quiet https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/cto2qv7nx6yq19logfcissyy4euo8lho.json
-O world_countries.json sfgeo=r'world_countries.json'

sfmap=folium.Map(location=[37.77986,-122.42905],zoom_start=12)

threshold_scale = np.linspace(df1_count['Count'].min(), df1_count['Count'].max(), 6, dtype=int) 
threshold_scale = threshold_scale.tolist()


sfmap.choropleth(geo_data=sfgeo,
            data=df1_count,
            columns=['PdDistrict','Count'],
            bins = threshold_scale,
            key_on='feature.properties.name',
            fill_color = 'YlOrRd',
            fill_opacity = 0.7,
            line_opacity=0.2,
            legend_name='Rate'                
            )

sfmap
```

The error reported is as below

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-1f74ef523c22> in <module>
 13                 fill_opacity = 0.7,
 14                 line_opacity=0.2,
---> 15                 legend_name='Rate'
 16                 )
 17 

TypeError: choropleth() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bins'
```

For the record and easy to follow, this is my df1_count dataframe (censored because someone might "steal" this, which means I'm violating the code of the course)

[image]

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```py
folium.Choropleth(geo_data=sfgeo,
            data=df1_count,
            columns=['PdDistrict','Count'],
            bins = threshold_scale,
            key_on='feature.properties.name',
            fill_color = 'YlOrRd',
            fill_opacity = 0.7,
            line_opacity=0.2,
            legend_name='Rate'                
).add_to(sfmap)
```

Comment: I have another error (well, progress, it's *another* error after all)

AttributeError: module 'folium' has no attribute 'Choropleth'

Comment: So maybe package isn't properly installed (py version etc). Try install folium with pip3 and execute this code with python3.

Comment: This [linl](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/installing.html) shows that pip installation of folium is the same as the method I used. I give it a try (replacing "$" with "!"), and the situation is the same.

Note: I'm using Jupyter notebook (an online workspace), so things might change with standard Python IDE on the computer